# Removing a float from a string by php and regex

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I have a [code](https://eval.in/137827) written in PAWN for SA-MP,
I sorted this code by several preg_replace calls with PHP and this is the semi-final code.

Final step is to remove the third parameter (They're Z-coordinates) with preg_replace which is float. like this:

```
SILLY4 = GangZoneCreate(-2178.69, -599.884, -0.00012207, -1794.92, -324.114);
```

to

```
SILLY4 = GangZoneCreate(-2178.69, -599.884, -1794.92, -324.114);
```

Comment: They're __all__ floats.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the third?

Comment: Convert your floats to strings and then use regex (string)$var, BUT What is the senese of it?

Comment: This is for SA-MP. This are the gang zones for my server. i replaced several times from the info.zon (orginal GTA: SA zone info) https://eval.in/137830 the semi-final code is here : https://eval.in/137827 and i want just x, y coords . third param is z and i not need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should do what you want: it removes the third parameter in the code.

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?m)^([^=]+= GangZoneCreate\(([^,]+,){2})(?2)((?2)[^)]+\);)$/', '\1\3', $subject);
```

Comment: @iFarbod Thanks for sending your whole string. I changed the regex. It matches everything. Assign your whole big string to $subject, run the regex. Your cleaned up string will be in $result.

Comment: with your last code , i got this : https://eval.in/137833 but some lines are some unreplaced texts : like line 121

Comment: @iFarbod No problem, fixed now. The expression matching the string name was too complex. Fixed it. Please see https://eval.in/137834